# Open facebook comment

Tags: android, facebook

my application allows users to quickly comment on a post. Currently my solution is to use:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("fb://facewebmodal/fhref=https://www.facebook.com/groups/groupId/permalink/feedId"));
activity.startActivity(intent);
```

However, it is too slow. Any suggestions are welcome.

P/s: open `facebook application` not `webview`

Comment: suggestion: use the facebook sdk instead of static URIs

Comment: Thanks, I am looking at facebook sdk :D